# ¿Cómo mandar los datos de arduino a una función en javascript en base en una página web y almacenar los datos en una variable?

Tags: javascript, arduino

**Código Arduino:**

```
#include <DHT.h>
#define DHTPIN A0
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  float t = dht.readTemperature();  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(t);

  delay(5000);
}
```

**Código javascript:**

```
<script>
       function cambio(){
           var circulo = 20;
           var d= document.getElementById("circulo");
           if (circulo <= 10) d.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
           else if (circulo <= 20) d.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
           else if (circulo <= 30) d.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
           else if (circulo <= 40) d.style.backgroundColor = "#2d792d";
           else if (circulo <= 50) d.style.backgroundColor = "#04ad04";
       } 

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  cambio() // Llamo a la función cambio()
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Hola Camilo, por lo que veo no tienes ningún modulo de conexión. ¿Usas solo el serial?

Comment: si solo es el serial, ocuparia otra cosa a parte del serial?

Comment: Tienes que leer el dato depositado en el puerto serial, por ejemplo con JAVA y enviarlo a tu servidor. Si quieres enviar el dato directamente puede utilizar un modulo TCP o ESP8266 para conectarte.

Comment: pues si ya estoy leyendo el dato con javascript  y lo envio a un servidor, como es nodejs pero ahi ya no se como almacenarlo en una variable nada mas lo leo

Comment: Quizas esto pueda ayudarlo [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js]

Comment: gracias lo revisare

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de diferentes maneras. La más simple es utilizar una librería que se llama Jhony Five. Aquí te dejo un tutorial para [controlar Arduino vía web](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/arduino-via-web-con-firmata/)

Aún así, yo te recomiendo que utilices una plataforma en la nube para el IoT o para cualquier otro propósito. Por ejemplo funciona bien Firebase.

A través de una API Rest podrás acceder a los datos. Aquí te dejo un tutorial de [Arduino y Firebase](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/geolocalizacion-wifi-arduino-nodemcu/).

Comment: muchas gracias lo tomare en cuenta